# C# TestClass on Mac

Tags: c#, macos

I am trying to get a file working on OS X which requires the use of the [TestClass()] and [TestMethod()] attributes. Im new to c# (Ive used java for a few years now) so Im not sure, but I think these attributes are part of Microsoft.VisualStudio. Since I'm on OS X I an using mono to compile and run C# files. How, if possible, can I get the same functionality as the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting namespace?

Comment: Check out NUnit, it runs on mono: http://www.mono-project.com/archived/nunit/

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin Studio / Monodevelop has a unit testing add-in which allows running NUnit tests within the IDE. The add-in should be installed by default. If not, you can install it through *Tools > Add-ins*.

When you build a class that has `[TestFixture]` attribute and it has a method with `[Test]` attribute - you can run it from **View > Pads > Unit Tests** or green icon at signature line. In this screenshot, lines 12 and 26:

[image]

Additionally, there should be a project template which already has NUnit package pre-installed and a test class ready:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[TestClass()]  and [TestMethod()] are part of MSTest framework and are not available in Mono.

Have you looked at using a mono build of [Nunit](http://www.mono-project.com/community/contributing/test-suite/) you can also use "using mapping" to convert you ms test attributes to nunit here is an example http://www.martinwilley.com/net/code/nunitmstest.html

If using mono isn't a requirement, you could also look at using [.NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/core) it's still in development but it's the full .net stack by Microsoft for OSX and Linux